# Simple calculus question (limits)

Tags: calculus, limits

So I have to calculate the following limit  $$\lim_{u\rightarrow 1}\frac{\frac{2u}{3}-\frac{2}{3u^2}}{2\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{3}-1+\frac{2}{3u}}}.$$

I tried to use L'Hopitals rule, but it doesnt work it seems, because every time I use it, I will get the same limit I have to calculate, since the derivative of the denominator is again of this form.

Comment: what about getting rid of all those fractions? Simplify both the numerator and denominator, then apply hopital or better taylor expansions :-)

Comment: L'Hospital won't work for the reason you said. So you need to dig into it, simplify and then take the limit. Hint: Factor out of the numerator $\frac{1}{u^{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ out of the root and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first clear out all the denominators: $$\frac{\frac{2u}{3}-\frac{2}{3u^{2}}}{2\sqrt{{\frac{u^{2}}{3}}-1+\frac{2}{3u}}}=\frac{u^{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}u^{3/2}\sqrt{u^{3}-3u+2}}=\frac{(u-1)(u^{2}+u+1)}{\sqrt{3}u^{3/2}\sqrt{(u-1)^2(u+2)}}$$
What do you think this tends to? Can you prove it?

Comment: @columbus8myhw I was leaving that for the OP

Comment: Deleted, then.${}$

Comment: I can get rid of the $\sqrt{u-1}$ to get $\frac{\sqrt{u-1}(u^2+u+1)}{\sqrt{3}u^2\sqrt{u+3}}$. So the limit must be 0. I just tried using wolframalpha, there it says it must be 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Argh I copied the expression incorrectly! One second, I'll correct it

Comment: The limit should now indeed be 1

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we try to put everything in the square root then you can apply L'Hopital. That is,

$$
\frac{\frac{2}{3}(u-\frac{1}{u^2})}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{u^2-3+\frac{2}{u}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{\frac{(u-\frac{1}{u^2})^2}{u^2-3+\frac{2}{u}}}
$$
Applying L'Hopital,

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{\frac{2(u-\frac{1}{u^2})(1+\frac{2}{u^3})}{2u-\frac{2}{u^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{u^3}}\to 1
$$